# Using addQuickSearch() with Grid

Tags: atk4

I was using without problem the method addQuickSearch() in older versions 4.03 and 4.b1 but now, when I use $g->addquickSearch(array('field1','field2')) the result in screen when I access the page is

```
BaseException

Trying to get value of not-existing field: q

/var/www/soporte/atk4/lib/BaseException.php:42
Stack trace:
/var/www/soporte/atk4/lib/BaseException.php :42     BaseException    BaseException->collectBasicData(Null, 1, 0)
/var/www/soporte/atk4/lib/Form/Basic.php    :187    BaseException       BaseException->__construct("Trying to get value of not-existing field: q")
/var/www/soporte/atk4/lib/QuickSearch.php   :97     sample_project_regla_grid_quicksearch   Form_Basic->get("q")
/var/www/soporte/atk4/lib/Filter.php    :59      sample_project_regla_grid_quicksearch  QuickSearch->applyDQ(Object(DBlite_dsql))
/   :   sample_project_regla_grid_quicksearch   Filter->applyHook()
/var/www/soporte/atk4/lib/AbstractObject.php    :337        call_user_func_array(Array(2), Array(0))
/var/www/soporte/atk4/lib/ApiWeb.php    :204    sample_project  AbstractObject->hook("post-submit")
/var/www/soporte/index.php  :15     sample_project  ApiWeb->main()
```

Something has changed ?

The api reference isn't diferent for this in older versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug. Thanks for pointing out.

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/17

switch to master until next stable release.