# How to add filter and quicksearch to ATK$ CRUD

Tags: php, frameworks, crud, atk4

I have a page in ATK4 that looks like this

```
<?php

class page_backlog extends Page
{

    function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $p = $this;

        $logged_in_users_team = $p->api->getTeamID();
        $s = $p->add('Model_BacklogStory');
        $s->addCondition('team_id', $logged_in_users_team);
        $s->addCondition('side_task', 0);

        $crud = $p->add('CRUD');
        $c = $crud->setModel($s, null, array('description', 'backlog_ref', 'points', 'priority_no'));

        if ($c->grid) {
            $c->grid->last_column = 'points';
            $c->grid->getColumn('points')->makeSortable();
            $c->grid->addQuickSearch(array('description', 'backlog_ref'));
        }
    }

}
```

with the code taken from the [agiletoolkit documentation](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/tutorial/jobeet/day9)

The grid displays but the quicksearch and sort link on the points field do not.
Instead there is an error at the top of the page

> C:\wamp\www\test1\page/backlog.php:16 [8] Undefined property: Controller::$grid

Where line 16 is       `if($c->grid){`

Any suggestions as to what i have missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah.

```
$c=$crud->setModel($s, null, array('description', 'backlog_ref', 'points','priority_no'));
```

this makes $c to become a Model and from this line further $c does not reference crud.
therefore use either `if ($crud->grid)` or add line `$c = $crud;`

Comment: Actually $c is a controller, but since it's transparent, it can be used as a model.

Comment: using if ($crud->grid) gives another error "Trying to get value of not-existing field: q" which suggests it doesnt see the query built by the model - i tried that before changing it to use $c as the latter displays the grid - just not the quicksearch or sort link

Comment: I also double checked all four columns listed are in the model so any other ideas how to get this to work ?

Comment: Found this latter error appears to be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260290/using-addquicksearch-with-grid which seems to be an issue with 4.1 but changing to use $crud does have a different effect from $c.

Comment: Try to switch to devel branch

Comment: I already made the two changes as per git issue 17 and this is now working as expected. Thanks

Comment: Thanks - I think ATK4  has great potential and I much prefer it to yii or other frameworks i looked at for the kind of web projects i have in mind. Also the MVC code separation makes it very clean compared to the old code i had which was a mix of php, css and jquery all in the same file.